# Search for two values and copy everything in between in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which has many terms in Column A.I want to search for two terms for example 
term A and term B and copy all rows between the two terms and paste it into a new sheet.These two terms may repeat in the column. The problem which I am basically facing the following  problem :  whenever I run my code it also copies rows between term B and term A which is unnecessary. Following is the code i am using for two terms term A and term B.
For example my column A is

Institute
   Event
   Job
   Computer
   Laptop
   Figures
   Event
   figures
   format
   computer

and many more terms
I want to copy all the rows between term A: Event and term B: Laptop and paste it into a new sheet. What my code is doing is it is copying the rows between all combinations of Event and computer. Even the rows between computer and event are copied(in this case Figure and laptop).

```
Sub OpenHTMLpage_SearchIt()
    Dim Cell As Range, Keyword$, N%, SearchAgain As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim ass As Variant
    Dim Cellev As Range, prakash$, P%, SearchAgaina As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim asa As Variant


StartSearch:
    N = 1
    Keyword = "Event"

    If Keyword = Empty Then GoTo StartSearch
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:A500")
        If Cell Like "*" & Keyword & "*" Then

        ass = Cell.Address

        P = 1
        prakash = "Computer"
        If prakash = Empty Then GoTo StartSearch
            For Each Cellev In Range("A1:A500")
                If Cellev Like "*" & prakash & "*" Then
                    asa = Cellev.Address

                    Range(asa, ass).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    Range("B13").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

                    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
                    P = P + 1
                End If
            Next Cellev
            N = N + 1
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Edit: code formatting.

Comment: Please format your code adequately. Additionally, please provide an example of your data and the result you wish to obtain. E.g.:
Term A: 1. Term B: 2. Data example: [1; 2; 3; 1; 0; 2]. Desired result: [1; 2], [1; 0; 2].

Comment: @mkingston I am really sorry for the inconvenience caused.I am very new to coding and stackoverflow and don't know the format clearly. I have edited my question and tried to be clear as possible. Kindly know if there is anything more to do.

Comment: I've edited your code for formatting so you can see how it should be done. It's awaiting a review so you'll see it once that's been done.

Comment: @mkingston I did try. Problem: My column is Institute Event Job Computer Laptop Figures Event figures format computer Laptop I want to copy 'Event Job Computer Laptop' and Event figures format computer Laptop and not 'Event Job Computer Laptop Figures Event figures format computer Laptop' Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The following is the code which is working for me.This copies everything in between Event and laptop and pastes it into a new sheet. Then again it searches for a second time and this time the search will start from the next row to the first search.I hope I am clear with this.

```
  Sub Star123()
   Dim rownum As Long
   Dim colnum As Long
   Dim startrow As Long
   Dim endrow As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long
   rownum = 1
   colnum = 1
   lastrow = Worksheets("Startsheet").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StartSheet").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)


   For rownum = 1 To lastrow
    Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Event" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If

       rownum = rownum + 1


   If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

   Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Laptop"
   endrow = rownum
   rownum = rownum + 1

   Worksheets("StartSheet").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy


   Sheets("Result").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste


   Next rownum
   End With
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub DoEeeeeet(sheetName, termA, termB)

    Dim foundA As Range, _
        foundB As Range
    Dim newSht As Worksheet

    With Sheets(sheetName).Columns(1)
        Set foundA = .Find(termA)
        If Not foundA Is Nothing Then
            Set foundB = .Find(termB, after:=foundA, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        End If
    End With

    If foundA Is Nothing Or foundB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find " & IIf(foundA Is Nothing, termA, termB)
    Else
        Range(foundA, foundB).Copy
        Set newSht = Sheets.Add
        newSht.Range("B13").PasteSpecial
    End If

End Sub
```

You can call it as follows:

```
DoEeeeeet "Sheet1","Event","Laptop"
```

It'll find the first instance of "Event" and the last instance of "Laptop" on the sheet named "Sheet1" and copy all of that data to B13 and subsequent cells in a new sheet.

Is that what you want? Or do you want each of the subranges beginning with "Event" and ending with "Laptop"?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want the subranges too. I am want copy all the possible rows between event and job.

Comment: Have you tried my code? Your comment indicates to me that you haven't. It copies all of the cells between the first instance "Event" and the final instance of "Laptop", inclusive. Please specify whether you have tried the code and what it did or didn't do that was unsuitable.

Comment: I did try.
Problem: My column is 
Institute Event Job Computer Laptop Figures Event figures format computer Laptop 
I want to copy 'Event Job Computer Laptop'  and Event figures format computer Laptop  and not 'Event Job Computer Laptop Figures Event figures format computer Laptop'
Is it possible?

Comment: @ankitagrawal, sorry it took a while to get back to you, I've been away for a long weekend. See the revised code, it'll find the first instance of termA, then the next instance of termB. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: No problems and thanks for the reply. As I said before there are many terms A and terms B in column. I want rows between ALL terms A and all terms B. Anyways I finally could write the code for it. I am uploading it here. Kindly see it