# Copy rows between two values VBA and paste to new sheet loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out some code here, I have looked on a few sites now, including here and it almost works but it is most likely my datasheet that is causing the issue.
This: [Search for two values and copy everything in between in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337167/search-for-two-values-and-copy-everything-in-between-in-a-loop)
and this: [I need code to copy between two rows and paste into the another sheet with our giving any values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920245/i-need-code-to-copy-between-two-rows-and-paste-into-the-another-sheet-with-our-g)

Would probably work, however the first value cannot be found. Let me explain.

I have an exported report from a website, it groups the totals with a name (value 1) and then the word totals for: (word 2).

What I need it to do is only copy and paste where value 1 is met , and value 2 will always be "totals for:".
Problem is with this loop is that there are blanks between each group of data, so it finds the first "totals for:" but cannot find my first value because it is between about 20 blank cells. (19 groups of data - with a blank row between each group).

How can i retro fix the above codes so that it keeps going down the rows, regardless of blanks to find the first value, then find the second value. Copy that range to a new sheet, and repeat this with a new value 1?

```
Sub MoveRows()
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim colnum As Integer
Dim startrow As Integer
Dim endrow As Integer

rownum = 1
colnum = 1

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Do
       If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch" Then
          startrow = rownum
       End If
       rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Totals for:"
    endrow = rownum
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy

 End With
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste




End Sub


Sub Star123()
Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
rownum = 1
colnum = 1
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastrow)


For rownum = 1 To lastrow
 Do
    If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch" Then
       startrow = rownum
    End If

    rownum = rownum + 1


 If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

 Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Totals for:"
 endrow = rownum
 rownum = rownum + 1

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Copy


 Sheets("Sheet2").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste


 Next rownum
 End With
 End Sub
```

I attached the codes that almost work, but cannot find my first value.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand what you're asking but using the code you've got as the basis if you do two loops. First loop to find the first row, loop until ="LIFEC - Supp Life - Ch". 2nd Loop to find the 2nd value, loop until= "Totals for:" Or you could use FIND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Find` method which looks something like:

```
Dim s As Range, e As Range
With Sheet1 'or this can be any other sheet where you search
    Set r = .Range("A:A").Find("Whatever you want found")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set e = .Range("A:A").Find("The other end", r)
        If Not e Is Nothing Then
            .Range(r, e).EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1") 'or to whatever sheet
        End If
    End If
End With
```

You can then have this in a loop which replaces the strings you want found. HTH.

Comment: L42...thank you.... thank you thank you... this is perfect.. now ill just make it a loop. I could not see this as an answer for the life of me, thank you